How to get the user flow ID from Azure Entra ID?
I am trying to disable sign-up flow from my user flow. Apparently, this need to be done by Graph API as described here.
I am stuck trying to retrieve the user flow ID. I get the following error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AADB2C",
    "message": "The application does not have any of the required application permissions (Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationFlows, EventListener.Read.All, EventListener.ReadWrite.All, Application.Read.All, Application.ReadWrite.All) to access the resource. "
  }
}

First, I make a request to get an access token.
POST https://{{domain}}.ciamlogin.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com:443
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={{clientId}}
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret={{clientSecrect}}
&grant_type=client_credentials

Second, I make a request to get the user flow ID.
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/authenticationEventsFlows HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{accessToken}}

I get the described permission error above. But I can see that my application has the permission added.


Could you decode the access token in jwt.ms and include what values aud and roles claim has? Please confirm whether your tenant is external customer tenant or not by adding application Overview Endpoints Portal image.

@Sridevi The tenant was created following the docs here. Therefore, I understand it is an external tenant. And yes, decoding the token, I can see the role: "roles: ["Policy.ReadWrite.AuthenticationFlows"]

Nevertheless, it is working today! It may be that the permissions took time to propagate yesterday when I posted the question. Or, I was not logged in with an admin account in the browser. Which I am today. Thanks
